# Perform an HTTP request in UNNotificationServiceExtension

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I need to call a backend service when my app receives a remote push notification, even when the app is killed. To do this I intercept the notification using a UNNotificationServiceExtension, in the "didReceive" method, and I perform a http request in the body of this method. Is this a dangerous procedure? Can this cause some problems, eg a rejection from the Apple Store?

Comment: You can do whatever is allowed to do in regular apps. Though the timing constraints are a little bit harder.

Comment: Thank you Cristik! By "timing constraints" you mean that a process cannot last for too much time (Eg if my http request is waiting for a response from the server for 10 seconts) ?

Comment: yes, extensions are given a limited amount of time to run.

Comment: Perfect, thank you again!

Comment: Have you been able to get this to work for you? The issue that we're having is that if the app is not running (killed by user, restart of device) the UNNotificationActions are not being executed.

Comment: For me it's working fine.
We managed to perform a HTTP request and the server receives it correctly even when the app's not running. Before trying to make a HTTP request I simply forced the UNNotificationServiceExtension to change the notification's title, in order to understand if it's working of not (debugging via xcode didn't work for me, I tried everything). After we performed a call to a web server using session.dataTask, and the server receives the data correctly. Did you try to alterate the notification's body or title, and see if it works when the app is not being executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely do what you want, but remember you only get around 30 seconds and that you need to use a synchronous, not async download.  If you use an async download it'll likely be killed as soon as your completion handler calls, which will happen before your download completes.

Comment: What if we call asynchronous and handle completion handler in response either it succeeds or failed.

Comment: You have to call the completion handler before the method exits.

Comment: This is not correct. It doesn't need to be synchronous. As recommended by apple during wwdc2016 you should use URLSession.